# Cannot build RPM packages from SRPM using mock

Tags: yum, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec, mock

I've successfully built the SRPM and after that step I'm trying to build the RPM from the SRPM. Following is the directory from where I am building the RPM. THe Source RPM are in the following directory.

```
$ ls
$ agent-ovs  genie  libopflex  libopflex-metadata  LICENSE  repo  sample  target
```

Then in order to build the RPM, I am using `mockchain` as follows:

```
$ mockchain -m --nocheck -r epel-7-x86_64 -a file://`pwd`/repo/ \
  -l target libopflex/*.src.rpm genie/target/libmodelgbp/*.src.rpm \
  agent-ovs/*.src.rpm
```

Once I do the above I get the following error. When I check the URLs, they are not present. How do I debug this, I don't even know from where the `mockchain` is fetching this URL's and the `repomd.xml`.

```
INFO buildroot.py:295:  Mock Version: 1.2.12
DEBUG util.py:94:  ensuring that dir exists: /var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64-noiro-28879/root/dev/pts
DEBUG util.py:97:  creating dir: /var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64-noiro-28879/root/dev/pts
DEBUG util.py:94:  ensuring that dir exists: /var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64-noiro-28879/root/dev/shm
DEBUG util.py:97:  creating dir: /var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64-noiro-28879/root/dev/shm
DEBUG buildroot.py:433:  kernel version == 3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64
DEBUG util.py:106:  touching file: /var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64-noiro-28879/root/etc/fstab
DEBUG util.py:106:  touching file: /var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64-noiro-28879/root/var/log/yum.log
DEBUG util.py:508:  child environment: None
DEBUG util.py:441:  Executing command: ['/bin/mount', '-n', '-t', 'proc', 'proc', '/var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64-noiro-28879/root/proc'] with env {'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'TERM': 'vt100', 'SHELL': '/bin/sh', 'HOSTNAME': 'mock', 'HOME': '/builddir', 'PATH': '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'} and shell False
DEBUG util.py:488:  Child return code was: 0
DEBUG util.py:508:  child environment: None
DEBUG util.py:441:  Executing command: ['/bin/mount', '-n', '-t', 'sysfs', 'sysfs', '/var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64-noiro-28879/root/sys'] with env {'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'TERM': 'vt100', 'SHELL': '/bin/sh', 'HOSTNAME': 'mock', 'HOME': '/builddir', 'PATH': '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'} and shell False
DEBUG util.py:488:  Child return code was: 0
DEBUG util.py:508:  child environment: None
DEBUG util.py:441:  Executing command: ['/bin/mount', '-n', '-t', 'tmpfs', 'tmpfs', '/var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64-noiro-28879/root/dev/shm'] with env {'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'TERM': 'vt100', 'SHELL': '/bin/sh', 'HOSTNAME': 'mock', 'HOME': '/builddir', 'PATH': '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'} and shell False
DEBUG util.py:488:  Child return code was: 0
DEBUG util.py:508:  child environment: None
DEBUG util.py:441:  Executing command: ['/bin/mount', '-n', '-t', 'devpts', '-o', 'gid=5,mode=0620,ptmxmode=0666,newinstance', 'devpts', '/var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64-noiro-28879/root/dev/pts'] with env {'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'TERM': 'vt100', 'SHELL': '/bin/sh', 'HOSTNAME': 'mock', 'HOME': '/builddir', 'PATH': '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'} and shell False
DEBUG util.py:488:  Child return code was: 0
DEBUG util.py:508:  child environment: None
DEBUG util.py:441:  Executing command: ['/bin/mount', '-n', '--bind', '/var/cache/mock/epel-7-x86_64/yum_cache/', '/var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64-noiro-28879/root/var/cache/yum/'] with env {'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'TERM': 'vt100', 'SHELL': '/bin/sh', 'HOSTNAME': 'mock', 'HOME': '/builddir', 'PATH': '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'} and shell False
DEBUG util.py:488:  Child return code was: 0
DEBUG util.py:508:  child environment: None
DEBUG util.py:441:  Executing command: ['/bin/mount', '-n', '--bind', '/var/cache/mock/epel-7-x86_64/ccache/u1000/', '/var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64-noiro-28879/root/tmp/ccache'] with env {'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'TERM': 'vt100', 'SHELL': '/bin/sh', 'HOSTNAME': 'mock', 'HOME': '/builddir', 'PATH': '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'} and shell False
DEBUG util.py:488:  Child return code was: 0
DEBUG buildroot.py:132:  rootdir = /var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64-noiro-28879/root
DEBUG buildroot.py:133:  resultdir = /home/noiro/workspace/team_noiro_engineering/Opflex-master_RPM/target/results/epel-7-x86_64/libmodelgbp-1.9.0-2.el7
DEBUG util.py:94:  ensuring that dir exists: /var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64-noiro-28879/root/etc/pki/mock
DEBUG util.py:97:  creating dir: /var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64-noiro-28879/root/etc/pki/mock
DEBUG util.py:94:  ensuring that dir exists: /var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64-noiro-28879/root/etc/yum/pluginconf.d
DEBUG util.py:97:  creating dir: /var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64-noiro-28879/root/etc/yum/pluginconf.d
DEBUG package_manager.py:178:  configure yum
DEBUG package_manager.py:184:  configure yum priorities
DEBUG package_manager.py:186:  configure yum rhnplugin
DEBUG package_manager.py:77:  ['/usr/bin/yum', '--installroot', '/var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64-noiro-28879/root/', '--releasever', '7', 'install', '@buildsys-build']
DEBUG util.py:508:  child environment: None
DEBUG util.py:441:  Executing command: ['/usr/bin/yum', '--installroot', '/var/lib/mock/epel-7-x86_64-noiro-28879/root/', '--releasever', '7', 'install', '@buildsys-build'] with env {'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'TERM': 'vt100', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'LC_MESSAGES': 'C', 'HOSTNAME': 'mock', 'PROMPT_COMMAND': 'printf "\x1b]0;<mock-chroot>\x07<mock-chroot>"', 'PATH': '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin', 'CCACHE_DIR': '/tmp/ccache', 'HOME': '/builddir', 'CCACHE_UMASK': '002'} and shell False
DEBUG util.py:377:  Not using downloaded repomd.xml because it is older than what we have:
DEBUG util.py:377:    Current   : Wed May 23 08:25:37 2018
DEBUG util.py:377:    Downloaded: Mon Mar  5 10:53:23 2018
DEBUG util.py:377:  http://mirror.datto.com/fedora/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/8224258b31fc16b72cdee55b19d8b214a0ad8d47f8ad32adcaa574fc8247f286-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
DEBUG util.py:377:  Trying other mirror.
DEBUG util.py:377:  https://mirrors.cat.pdx.edu/epel/7/x86_64/repodata/8224258b31fc16b72cdee55b19d8b214a0ad8d47f8ad32adcaa574fc8247f286-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
DEBUG util.py:377:  Trying other mirror.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `yum` repositories for `mockchain`, and the `mock` command it executes, would come from the configuration you specified, "epel-7-x86_64" and any `--addrepo=` flags used on the command line.  The configuration would normally be located at `/etc/mock/$CONFIG.cfg` or in this case, `/etc/mock/epel-7-x86_64.cfg`.

The current `repomd.xml` appears to be coming from local `yum` cache on the build machine, remove it with `yum clean all` if necessary.

For more verbose output useful for additional debugging, you should be able to pass `-m --verbose` to `mockchain`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding. It looks like the repomd.xml is indeed coming from the yum cache, i.e "/var/cache/mock/epel-7-x86_64/yum_cache/epel". But, when I do "yum clean all", only the "epel-myrepo" and "rhel-myrepo" gets cleaned but, nothing happens in "/var/cache/mock/epel-7-x86_64/yum_cache/epel", and "/var/cache/mock/epel-7-x86_64/yum_cache/epel" is the place from where the repomd.xml is getting used.

Comment: Also, how to tell the mock to use the local repo for the yum install rather than the yum cache.

Comment: To clear the `mock` cache, I think `mock -r epel-7-x86_64 --scrub=yum-cache` should be able to do it.  IIRC, the initial creation of the `mock` chroot will use the local machine's yum cache, then all actions within the chroot will use the `mock` yum cache.  I do not think you can disable that behavior, but once you clear the yum cache it should download a fresh copy all the repositories.